# Education - can it be countable noun used with article?

Tags: articles

> The development of **popular education** since the beginning of the century has been rapid. People have gradually begun to realize the value of **a good education**.

In this text, **popular education** has no article, and **good education** has the article **a**.

The dictionary says **education** is an uncountable noun. Please explain the article in **a good education**.

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about one example of a particular type of an uncountable noun, it is possible to use an article with it.

According to the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cheese), **cheese** is normally uncountable, but if you refer to one example of a particular type of cheese, you can also treat it as countable:

> **a** cow's milk cheese

When you apply **good** to something, you are talking about a particular type of whatever-it-is, so you can treat it as countable:

> A man can make **a good cheese** with 44% moisture; but I don't care if it is 44% or 34%, if it hasn't got the flavor and quality, you cannot sell it. - *Annual Meeting of the Wisconsin Cheese Makers' Association*

Note that there are other situations when a normally uncountable noun can be countable: see the link I provided above for more examples.

Comment: The dictionary says ‘conscience’ can be both countable and uncountable noun. Then when it should be written with article ‘a’?

“The best equipment ... is a conscience, common sense and health. ... Concience makes us ...”

Comment: @YounSunWoo, When you are talking about a person's conscience but not any person in particular, it's countable and it gets a determiner. When you are talking about conscience as an abstract concept, it is not countable. The sentence that you quoted contains examples of both.